# How to log with same log4j.properties files for two different Spring-Boot Applications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

Suppose I have two Spring-Boot applications called *config* and *eureka*.

*config* is made up of:

```
config 
  /src/main
    /java
      /com.example
        Demo.java
    /resources
      application.properties
```

*eureka* is made up of:

```
eureka 
  /src/main
    /java
      /com.example
        Demo.java
    /resources
      application.properties
```

I have a log4j.properties files

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] - %p [%t] --- %c : %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log.out
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]  - %p [%t] --- %c : %m%n
```

One way to log both *config* and *eureka* is by keeping a copy of this properties file in *resources* folder of both applications and giving a common path for the log file in both. I have tried this and this works correctly.

I want to do something different. I want to maintain a single log4j.properties file instead of two for both applications. My question is what is the proper way to do this? How?

Comment: On Linux, I guess you could use a symbolic link.

Comment: Thank you. What about in Windows?

Comment: This could be achieved with a _resources_ project, from which the other ones would depend. See the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492622/specify-common-resources-in-a-multi-module-maven-project

Comment: That answer is helpful but it would work if both of them were under a single project. In my case they both are independent projects. One way for me to do it would be to create a parent and do as how they have told in the other answer. I want to keep them separate and refer to a single configuration file. I don't know if this is possible. I'm quite new to this. So sorry if I keep asking silly questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep *log4j.properties* in common location (in *Windows c:\boots*), refer it in *application.properties*.

```
logging.config = C:\boots\log4j.properties
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Will this work if I were to put it in bootstrap.properties file instead of application.properties?