# Maven - Override test resource folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem with my tests in Maven and Eclipse.

I run my test suite from Eclipse and all works well, but when I run

```
mvn test
```

I have an exception and it appears when I'm trying to read some files in test cases like this:

```
final File javaFolder = new File("WEB-INF/test/file");
```

When I do that I have a Null Pointer Exception and debugging I saw that the path is

```
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\WEB-INF\test\file
```

In addition, I think that is important to say that I overwrote the test directory in my pom, because we need test sources in a special place. We did it in this way:

```
<testSourceDirectory>WEB-INF/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

So my question is: Why running tests with Maven is not getting the correct working directory? Could I define a specific folder to read some files? I tried with things like

```
getClass().getResource("myFile").getFile()
```

but when I printed the absolute path I had `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local...\myFile` again

Edit: I don't have a chance to follow the convention because I'm talking about a big system that has never used Maven so can't change all the directory structure. It is not my desition, sadly.

In addition, when I print my "user.dir" I have: `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp`

Edit2: my project path is in another partition `E:\work\myProject`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have your tried adding this to your pom.xml

```
       <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/test/file</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
```

Add this to the build section, it let you specify the location for the testResource folder and where the test classes are. Consider checking this [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html) as well, there is an example [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) that could help you to create the pom.xml.

Remember there is resource section and testResource section, you should modify the second one pointing to the correct site.

Also consider using `final File javaFolder = new File("classpath:/WEB-INF/test/file");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had this: `C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath:\WEB-INF\test\file` So I had a NPE again for obvious reasons :(

Comment: adding testResource directory is very likely to solve the problem *assuming* he's using the `getResource()` method mentioned in the post.  Incidentally that combo is the best way to keep the tests flexible.  Other solutions end up breaking when you change from, say, a build test to a test run as a web-app (which is my best guess for why they need to be in WEB-INF)

Comment: Moving my tests from WEB-INF to another folder could be an option. Do you recommend that?

Comment: Have you tied Class.getClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/test/file"), instead of hardcode the "classpath"

Answer (score 0):

The basic tenet of maven is convention over configuration. You may want to ask a honest question why you had to break out of the well established convention.

Did you try "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/test/file"

Update:
I think you should log the System.getProperty("user.dir") in your test case and make sure that the file is relative to the printed directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have the possibility to change the folder structure -sadly, it is not my desition- In other hand, I don't know why the path is C:\.... instead of src/main/webapp... So my test files are correctly compiled, the problem is with my resources.

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: When I print user.dir it comes with: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: What is the absolute path to your project ?

Comment: E:\work\myProject So is in another partition! Very strange :(

Comment: That's totally weird. Is your eclipse workspace C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp ?

Comment: No, my eclipse workspace is in the same partition: E:\workspace

Answer (score 0):

I think your resources directory is different too. 
So make sure you have setup your resource directory (not only your source directory) and load your file using getResourcesAsStream

Comment: I have no configuration in my pom that includes any resource :(