# Distribute lombok.config

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I'm wondering if it is possible to distribute a lombok.config through a parent pom. Let me elaborate. Say I have a parent pom referencing all kind of reusable components among other to be used libraries in `dependencyManagement`. Among these libraries is `lombok` and it is used by several components. Other projects will set our pom as parent and they have a base to work from. Lombok provides a [configuration](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) mechanism by means of a `lombok.config`. This is supposed to be set in the project root. At this point I don't see a way to distribute the configuration. How do I achieve this? Or is this impossible or an anti-pattern.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492622/specify-common-resources-in-a-multi-module-maven-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is nothing to do this... maybe it would be a nice feature, but for now, the configuration file has to be distribuited manually. However, to me it does not look as an anti-pattern. You are just overwriting the default policy of Lombok with yours, and it is a good practice to centralize this setting in your development infrastructure.

Maybe you should propose this feature to Project Lombok's guys.