# Spring boot multi-module properties not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I know there is a number of questions on this platform similar to this one but so far no solution has solved my problem.

The project was working just fine until I decided to modularize it, my folder structure looks like this

`Accounting - Parent`

`-> banking - Child`

`-> Commons - Child`

`-> Reports - Child`

`-> humaResourceManagement - Child`

`-> payRoll - Child`

`-> sales - Child`

[image: Snippet of the structure]

After creating the modules I noticed all the sudden my app could not locate `application.properties` in my parent project, the child projects as of now do not have  `.properties` so I know very well it is not a clash, before this was working I did not even need to `@PropertySource` annotations, it just worked but now it does not, for it to work I need to specify the properties like

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("file:src/main/resources/application.properties"),
```

})

I feel this is a horrible solution, also it seems other parts of the app are not able to access the same `application.properties`, my `properties` has the logging configs below

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Before Spring boot could log only `debug` logs but now it is logging `Info`, `warn` etc.

Below are my pom files

`Parent pom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>banking</module>
    <module>sales</module>
    <module>payRoll</module>
    <module>reports</module>
    <module>humanResourceManagement</module>
    <module>commons</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>ubuntu.software</groupId>
<artifactId>saltakaunting</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
    <disruptor.version>3.4.2</disruptor.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ubuntu.software</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>${disruptor.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
        <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`Banking pom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>saltakaunting</artifactId>
    <groupId>ubuntu.software</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>banking</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ubuntu.software</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`Commons pom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>saltakaunting</artifactId>
    <groupId>ubuntu.software</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>commons</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Someone help me figure out why my `application.properties` has stopped being loaded all the sudden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of '**jar**' packaging, by default JAR Plugin looks for 'src/main/resources' directory for the resources and bundled them along with code build (if not configured for custom resource directory etc).

But '**pom**' packaging doesn't work this way so application.properties is not included in build if it is not specified with some annotation etc.

Either you can create one more module which can be child to parent pom and parent to rest of modules to share one application.properties across whole project or you can use maven-remote-resources-plugin to use a remote resource bundle

[related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492699/10812004)

[maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources)

Comment: Yeah, this worked, although I only had to move my `properties` to my common since all my modules use it and it worked.